# Can all programs be converted to single assignment form?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Single assignment form is widely used in compilers for code optimization. However, I cannot find anywhere specifically written whether all programs be converted to single assignment form or not. If it is possible then please direct me to that material, otherwise please provide a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the authors of "A Practical Dynamic Single Assignment Transformation",
ACM TODAES 2007 and they confirmed that there are indeed limitations of applying
single assignment form.
For example, the solutions of the transportation problem (from Operations Research --
[link](http://orms.pef.czu.cz/text/transProblem.html)) cannot be converted since their execution depends upon data-dependent cost matrices. However, the authors also mentioned that pre-defined loop bounds can be applied based on architectural restrictions, etc., making them amenable to single assignment form.